# React Native: Iterating through an array of data pulled from firebase only renders the first item in the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

My `useEffect()` function is retrieving data from firebase and only renders one `<TaskItem/>` on the screen.

I pull the data and store it in temptasks in my state then that is rendered using map to display a component for each item.

There are five items in my backend firebase and using console log I can see they are all received but why is only the first one rendering. Re-rendering the page shows all 5.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(userId!=='' && id !== userId)
     setId(userId);

  if (id !== '') {
    let counter = 0;
      db.collection('users').doc(id).collection('tasks').onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
        const tempTasks = [];
          snapshot.forEach(
             doc => {
                var newData = doc.data();
                newData.id = doc.id;
                tempTasks.push(newData);
                setTasks(tempTasks);
             }
          )

        setTasks(tempTasks);
             
      });
  }
},[id, userId]);
```

```
<View style={styles.tasks}>
                    
                        {temptasks.map((task) => {
                            return (

                                <View style={{ margin: 4}}>
                                     <TaskItem/>
                                </View>
                            );
                        })}
                    </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no render because you update the state with the same array (it has the same reference). You have to return an enriched copy.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(userId!=='' && id !== userId)
     setId(userId);

  if (id !== '') {
    let counter = 0;
      db.collection('users').doc(id).collection('tasks').onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
        const tempTasks = [];
          snapshot.forEach(
             doc => {
                var newData = doc.data();
                newData.id = doc.id;
                tempTasks.push(newData);
                setTasks(tempTasks); // Not this
                setTasks([...tempTasks, newData]); // But this
             }
          )

        setTasks(tempTasks); // no effect
             
      });
  }
},[id, userId]);
```

Comment: I am receiving undefined though when I log tempTasks it appears to be empty?

Comment: Sorry it's  setTasks([...tempTasks, newData]); // But this

Comment: oh yes that was creating an object

Answer (score 1):

While Pierre's answer works perfectly fine, you can do the same with a lot less code by using the `docs` array, and a spread (`...`) operator:

```
db.collection('users').doc(id).collection('tasks').onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
  const tempTasks = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
    return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
  })

  setTasks(tempTasks);         
});
```

Or even shorter (although we might lose some readability in this step):

```
db.collection('users').doc(id).collection('tasks').onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
  setTasks(snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
    return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
  }));
});
```